# Entity Framework: nesting DbExecutionStrategy execution calls - will it work?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Has anybody had any experience with nesting `DbExecutionStrategy` calls?

Like this:

```
new ExecStrategy1(3, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200)).Execute(() => {
    new ExecStrategy2(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)).Execute(() => {
        // Execute SQL transaction
    }
});
```

Would both of the retry policies be applied?

Comment: Did you try to check it with SQL Profiler?

Comment: Hadn't got time to try to reproduce this in dev envrionment and check in SQL profiler. I was hoping maybe somebody has used nested calls and can share the experience.

Comment: Based on the [implementation](https://github.com/mrward/entityframework-sharpdevelop/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Infrastructure/DbExecutionStrategy.cs#L127) of the `Execute` method I can't see any constraint which prohibits the nesting.